Mysterious accessibility related crash
I am trying to figure out what causes the following crash reported by an app analytics:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.getItemViewType(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:553)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.adjustItemPositionForA11yDelegate(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:673)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.access$100(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:523)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:659)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate$ItemDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:163)
        at androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateAdapter.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:89)
        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8609)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(LinearLayoutCompat.java:1794)
        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:8570)
        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:29784)
        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8553)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1271)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1096)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:342)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:75)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:423)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.getItemViewType(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:553)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.adjustItemPositionForA11yDelegate(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:673)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.access$100(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:523)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:659)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate$ItemDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:163)
        at androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateAdapter.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:89)
        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8609)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(LinearLayoutCompat.java:1794)
        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:8570)
        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:29784)
        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8553)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1271)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1294)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1096)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:342)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:75)
        at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:423)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

The stack trace does not point to any app code. I test the app on different devices, but cannot produce any crashes.
It seems related to accessibility but I have no clue how accessibility is related to the app. The app does not do anything special for accessibility except for conventional practices.
Could anyone offer a tip on the possible causes?

Same story here. Came with a dependency upgrade.

I am starting to wonder if this crash happens upon app exit because we have not received any reports of perceived crashes from app users despite many such crash reports from app analytics.

I experienced this issue in automated tests. A menu button was clicked in the sidebar menu. The sidebar was closed as a consequence, and the app navigated to another fragment. UIAutomator2 did read the layout just after the click, causing the above exception (in 1 out of 10 tries). I added a short wait after the click, and the issue is gone.

That is a great hint. I am going to try this to see if I can reproduce it. We even receive such crash reports during Google Play's update validation and they have never rejected any updates with this crash, so this means even Google Play testers do not see the crash.
